# setting up gitolite repository hook

Tags: gitolite

I have set up a gitolite repository specific hook according to the documentation on page http://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html#hooks

I have enabled the `repo-specific-hooks` feature in the `.gitolite.rc` file.
I have created a directory `hooks/repo-specific` with the hook script within the gitolite-admin repository and added a `option hook.post-receive` line to the repo section in `gitolite.conf`.

Upon pushing the gitolite-admin repository I now get the error message

```
no files/dirs called 'hooks' or 'logs' are allowed
```

in the gitolite log and the custom `post-receive` hook is not set up by gitolite.
How do I set up the hook correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the information on the page
http://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html#hooks
is actually *wrong* for version 3.6.

The correct setup procedure is described on the page
http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook.html#v3.6-variation-repo-specific-hooks

The directory must be created as `local/hooks/repo-specific` not as `hooks/repo-specific`.